# How to use Padding in conv2d layer of specific size

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, padding, conv-neural-network

My input size image is :
`256 * 256`

Conv2d Kernal Size : `4*4` and strides at `2*2`.

The output will be `127*127`.
I want to pass to Max Pool for this i want to apply padding to make it `128*128` so that pooling works well and pooling output will be used in other layers.

How i can apply padding for this conv.

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, (4,4),strides=(2,2), activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

Comment: [It's in the docs.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d). Pass `padding="same"`.

Comment: what same will do , will it make the target dimensions

Comment: That is not a complete sentence.  Anyway, "same" padding will make it so that your images will stay 256x256 _before_ strides so with a stride of 2 you will end up getting images of size 128x128.

Comment: okay can you post this anwer so i can accept and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.layers.conv2d` has a `padding` parameter that you can use to do this. The default is `"valid"` which means no padding is done, so each convolution will slightly shrink the input. You can pass `padding="same"` instead. This will apply padding such that the output of the convolution is equal in size to the input. This is *before* strides, so using a stride of 2 will still downsample by a factor 2. In your example, using `padding="same"` should result in the convolution output to have size 128x128.